# Files seacher in Ubuntu Using C++

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, posix

I am planning on making a file searcher for Ubuntu OS in C++. My raw algorithm (not yet implemented in C++) takes a lot of time and sometime might fail to search a file, so I came up with the decision to search for files in the OS file table/Directory because the location and names of all the files and folders are already present in it. So my question is:

Is there any system call to access Ubuntu file table/Directory in C++

Answer (score 1):

I don't get your question because Ubuntu does not introduce new filesystems or other user-space-related things, so you can code for Ubuntu like you can code for any GNU/linux OS out there, but there are really good utilities already in place like `locate` and `find`.

Comment: I know these terminal commands but I am looking for clues to make this program so that I can understand practically, how file searching softwares work

Comment: just remember that those are open source utilities, if you don't like the terminal approach, browse their source code and try to get the most out of them.

Comment: And you could also use `strace` to understand what syscalls they are doing.

Answer (score 1):

You should be aware that Ubuntu is just a distribution of Linux and that Linux in turn has a standard Unix system API (often termed "POSIX"). Therefore you should better ask / search using the term "Linux" or "Unix" or even "POSIX" instead of "Ubuntu".

In Unix the basic syscalls for examing directories are:

- `opendir`, `readdir` and `closedir` and variants for reading the names inside a directory
- the `stat`  familiy (`stat`, `fstat`, `lstat`) for getting real information (file-type, size, ...) from a plain name.

If you look at the bottom of the man-pages for these syscalls you will find more relevant syscalls in the "SEE ALSO" section.

Comment: I mentioned Ubuntu because I thought the file system of Ubuntu might be different as compared to other Unix based OS..

Comment: Ubuntu uses the ext4 filesystem as any other Linux. Also: The format of the filesystem does not affect the programming API. That mapping is the job the kernel.